# Creating array in class constructor

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a class with 2 arrays where one will hold matrix of distance between cities and other will have identifiers to know which cities, howeverI don't know size of arrays prior to constructor, however, when I try to create it in constructor I get an error.

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

My code:

```
public class Distances{
    static int distancesArray[][];
    static Distance distanceIdentifiers[];
    static int ammountOfBreweries = 0;

    public Distances(int size) {
         distancesArray[][] = new int[size][size];
         distanceIdentifiers[] = new Brewerie[size];        
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, right, that every time you instantiate a `Distances` the `distancesArray`, being `static` will be reset for all instances?

Comment: I didn't know that, but this class will be used only once, so in this case it's not a problem.

Comment: @atilas1 but it may become a problem in the future, I recommend you to make the fields non-static.

Comment: The problem for me with non-static elements is that whenever I try to use one, I get an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to do this.

You dont have to use [][] symbols at the time of array initialization.

```
public class Distances{
    static int distancesArray[][];
    static Distance distanceIdentifiers[];
    static int ammountOfBreweries = 0;

    public Distances(int size) {
         distancesArray = new int[size][size];
         distanceIdentifiers = new Brewerie[size];        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a try,just remove `[]`

```
public Distances(int size) {
     distancesArray = new int[size][size];
     distanceIdentifier = new Brewerie[size];        
}
```